# Элементы с максимальной и минимальной суммой цифр

Tags: python, list

С клавиатуры вводится кол-во элементов массива и сам массив чисел. Размер массива не больше 100 элементов. Нужно вывести элемент с минимальной суммой цифр в одну строку(если таких несколько, вывести минимальный из них). А во вторую, элемент с максимальной суммой цифр(если таких несколько, вывести максимальный из них)

В примере ниже: 11(1+1=2);  21(2+1=3);  111(1+1+1=3), 2-минимальная сумма, 3-максимальная, но т.к. элементов с суммой цифр равной 3м-два, то выводится максимальный из них т.е. 111

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм действий, поскольку у меня даже нет идей как выполнить поставленную задачу

Я знаю как найти сумму цифр числа, но как из массива взять число для проверки(и при этом, в случае если чисел с минимальной/максимальной суммой несколько, определить какое из них стоит выводить)-не понимаю

Пример

**Вход**

3

11 21 111

**Выход**

11

111

Comment: ```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
print('min: '+str(min(a)))
print('max: '+str(max(a)))
#Я не понимаю что за 3 и куда его пихать

Comment: 3 это количество элементов массива

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def digits_sum(num):
    return sum([int(x) for x in str(num) if x.isdigit()])

items = ['11', '21', '111', '-1']

min_ = min((digits_sum(x), int(x)) for x in items)[1]
max_ = max((digits_sum(x), int(x)) for x in items)[1]
print(min_)
print(max_)
```

вывод на экран:

```
-1
111
```

Comment: место lambda лучше сразу создавать нужный кортеж `min((digits_sum(x), int(x)) for x in items)[1]`

Comment: @Danis, хорошая идея, спасибо!

Comment: немного изменил, сделал ввод с клавиатуры для items, но с отрицательными числами не работает

Comment: @MaxU 126 -123 45

Comment: @МаркМаркович, исправил ответ

Comment: @MaxU работает, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

1. Читаем длинну массива
2. Читаем каждый элемент
3. Ищем минимальный элемент в массиве `a`, где ключ - его сумма цифр
4. Так же с максимальным.

```
n = input()
a = input().split()
    
def f(x):
    return sum(map(int, x if int(x) > 0 else x[1:])) - 0 if int(x) > 0 else int(x[1])

print(min(a, key=f))
print(max(a, key=f))
```

Comment: если взять отрицательный элемент, то не работает

Comment: По условию задачи, максимальный элемент `111` т.к. `111 > 21` ;)